# What technology can be used to create liquid suit?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, physics

I'm new to **WorldBuilding**, so please let me know if I'm doing something wrong or should add more information! Thanks in advance.

---

### Explanation

- Liquid costume/suit is technological solution of future soldiers, that is using some technology. It might be some metal from other planet, which is structured by some magnetic field controlled by human inside the suit.
- The suit is totally bulletproof, because the material has great durability. Yet  ways of breaking the bonds of the suit still exist, such as sonic gun which spreads material out of the body. In addition, it is still liquid and has ability to change its shape.
- Shapes may be any type, but its size depends on volume of the material. The suit is able to generate edged weapons such as sword, claws or defensive shield, but it cannot produce complicated ones like guns etc. Applying material to constructing the weapon would lead to vulnerability, because other surface of the suit becomes thinner and less protected. In the world where almost every soldier has the same or even greater suit it is kind of huge risk, but sometimes risk pays off.
- Moreover, user inside the suit gains additional power and speed, because it serves as exoskeleton covering whole body and making movement much easier. Though, it may sound as a super power, but in real case it would boost the characteristics approximately twice. The user able to reach speeds up to 30 km per hour without the suit, may afford ~60km/h inside it etc.
- The suit is always colored as its source material and has no abilities to change it right now.

**Question:** What kind of technology can be the origin of this kind of suit?

---

### Notes

- *Not only real technologies can be used, because this is for my book*
- *We can take `Marvel's Venom` as an example, but suit shouldn't be alive as in this case.*

---

### References

- [**Marvel's Venom:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(Marvel_Comics_character)) Is the super-powered symbiosis of human and alien symbiote. The symbiote is a liquid creature that slowly gets control over the host once it have been parasitized. Liquid creature covers whole body of the host and grants them super powers.

Comment: Hi erumaru! Welcome to WorldBuilding! I think that, for the question to work well, you should describe more what you're trying to achieve. Worldbuilding is good filling the gaps, but not that good if the gaps are too big (because we can end with too many good answers), so is better to be more specific. Also I recommend not just saying "like X from X media", as not everyone necessarily is aware (or can be too aware) of that particular media, no matter how popular.

Comment: @Stormbolter Thanks! I will edit.

Comment: I think you should make the description of a "liquid suit" more descriptive, although I understand it and will answer.

Comment: @wpokdljnlnmn Ok!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking for lists of answers, which means no answer could ever be even remotely objectively right.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a better description/list of requirements (what do you **need** this suit to do/be, what do you **want** it to be/do, what would you **like** for it to possibly be/do, and similar for "must not be/do"), and then adjust your question - are you asking how it such a suit would work? Where it might be found? How it might be used?  How it might be fought? "Did you face this kind of suit or something close to it in some universe?" is more of a [scifi.se] question about what examples already exist, not Worldbuilding. You may want to read up on [ask] for tips too.

Comment: Hi Erumaru, thanks for your question. To me, it is still a bit unclear what you are looking for. If you were to immerge yourself in oil, it would stay on you. At least to some extend. Does that constitute a suit ? And do you want something realistic ? References to other fictions ?

Comment: A reminder to all, we have a [code of conduct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/conduct) and we are serious about enforcing it.

Comment: @Erumaru Looking much better, good work :)  If you add a short paragraph explaining the mandatory functions of the suit, then this should be ready for a Vote To Reopen (e.g. does it grant enhanced strength?  Does it have to be bulletproof?  Can it scan your surroundings and alert you to danger?  Can it shapeshift into claws/shields/weapons?  Change colour for camouflage?  To make for a good story, you probably don't want it to do *all* of these - at least not at first, leave room for upgrades and "high-spec"/more expensive suits later on)

Comment: @Chronocidal Hello! I've added more details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have thought of liquid suits as you call them and the major way that I think it could work would be to have it living, like venom. I don't think it could be fully liquid, although, maybe it could be a genetically engineered slime mold. it could possibly be controlled by some sort of network of wires spread throughout the suit. these wires could have particularly organized signals sent through them. you could engineer the mold to be attracted to electricity. this would only provide an aesthetic change and would not provide extra strength.
another method would be to edit the genes of an octopus or another cephalopod massively so it could accommodate a human inside its body, and essentially make it humanoid (although with a large cavity for a human). this would allow the human to change color, texture and basic form. this would also greatly increase the strength of the human. 
this is all semi-scientific because of the fact that this is a semi-scientific question.

Comment: very good one, I really appreciate your answer!